# Remove blank lines with grep

Tags: text, terminal, grep, newline

I tried `grep -v '^$'` in Linux and that didn't work. This file came from a Windows file system.

Answer (score 405, accepted):

Try the following:

```
grep -v -e '^$' foo.txt
```

The `-e` option allows regex patterns for matching.

The single quotes around `^$` makes it work for Cshell. Other shells will be happy with either single or double quotes.

UPDATE:  This works for me for a file with blank lines or "all white space" (such as windows lines with `\r\n` style line endings), whereas the above only removes files with blank lines and unix style line endings:

```
grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' foo.txt
```

Comment: That egrep would only work for files with zero or 1 space on the line, not for files with 2 or more spaces. Change ? to *.

Comment: This should be `grep -E -v`, everything after `-e` is interpreted as the pattern.

Comment: `grep -v -e '^[[:space:]]*$' -e '^#' file` will give you all non-blank, non-comment lines in a script or config file (or any file type that uses the hash character for comments).

Comment: "The `-e` option allows regex patterns for matching." That is very **misleading**. `-e` is a (POSIX-)definition for: `This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).` (from [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)). Grep already expects a (basic) regular expression by default. For this pattern, you may leave out `-e` entirely: `grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' foo.txt`.

Comment: If you're dealing with files that might have windows-style CR+LF line breaks but don't want to also exclude lines with other whitespace, then use this regex:   `'^[[:cnrl:]]?$'`.

Answer (score 122):

Keep it simple.

```
grep . filename.txt
```

Comment: this gives me all the lines in the file

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It should output all the lines in the file except blank lines.

Comment: This works for me on files from a linux based system but not on files from Windows. Presumably because of Windows line-ending characters.

Comment: I'm upvoting this even though it doesn't quite solve the OP's problem of handling a file with Windows line endings, but since I don't have that issue, this turned out to be the perfect solution for me.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Simple and worked on Linux.

Comment: This was a perfect solution for me:  $ grep . oracle_ddl.log|egrep -v "altered|created"

Comment: `grep ".+" filename.txt` will have same result but better performance while printing the output to the console

Comment: Ahh, the explanation makes sense - `.` matches anything except null terminator and newline (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67943782/295686) and [this](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html)). So this is saying the line has to have _something_ in it. If piping combine with your real query: `cat filename.txt | grep . | grep 'answer'`

Answer (score 39):

Use:

```
$ dos2unix file
$ grep -v "^$" file
```

Or just simply awk:

```
awk 'NF' file
```

If you don't have dos2unix, then you can use tools like [tr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
tr -d '\r' < "$file" > t ; mv t "$file"
```

Comment: Can't find the program dos2unix. Is that for Windows? the ask command doesn't work either.

Comment: ask?  No, that's `awk`.

Comment: Good point about converting to UNIX-style line endings otherwise regular expressions may not work as expected. Nothing here worked for me until I converted the line endings.

Answer (score 20):

```
grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$"

The -v makes it print lines that do not completely match

===Each part explained===
^             match start of line
[[:space:]]   match whitespace- spaces, tabs, carriage returns, etc.
*             previous match (whitespace) may exist from 0 to infinite times
$             match end of line
```

Running the code-

```
$ echo "
> hello
>       
> ok" |
> grep -v "^[[:space:]]*$"
hello
ok
```

To understand more about how/why this works, I recommend reading up on regular expressions. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: How and why does this work? Your answer would be much better if you could explain. For instance your regular expression matches the beginning of the string then one or more spaces using the POSIX standard then the end of the string, i.e. with grep -v it removes all lines that are only spaces. Right? What happens if there are no spaces; it's simply a newline character?

Comment: As my example shows, even only an empty line is removed (the first line). I added more information, so hopefully that helps. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you have sequences of multiple blank lines in a row, and would like only one blank line per sequence, try

```
grep -v "unwantedThing" foo.txt | cat -s
```

`cat -s` suppresses repeated empty output lines.

Your output would go from

```
match1



match2
```

to

```
match1

match2
```

The three blank lines in the original output would be compressed or "squeezed" into one blank line.

Answer (score 5):

Do lines in the file have whitespace characters?

If so then

`grep "\S" file.txt`

Otherwise

`grep . file.txt`

Answer obtained from:
https://serverfault.com/a/688789

Answer (score 4):

The same as the previous answers:

```
grep -v -e '^$' foo.txt
```

Here, `grep -e` means the extended version of [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep). '^$' means that there isn't any character between ^(Start of line) and $(end of line). '^' and '$' are regex characters.

So the command `grep -v` will print all the lines that do not match this pattern (No characters between ^ and $).

This way, empty blank lines are eliminated.

Comment: `-e` does not mean "the extended version of grep", maybe you are confused with `-E`? The manual clearly says that `-e` just explicitly says that a pattern follows. Since the pattern does not start with a dash, and you are only defining one pattern anyway, you might as well leave it out as by default grep expects one regex pattern: `grep -v '^$' foo.txt` (no need for extended regex functionality). Also it is worth mentioning that this does not eliminate the blank lines in the file, only that which is piped through the output. For that case, `sed -i` would be the right tool.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using `egrep`, though in my test with a genuine file with blank line your approach worked fine (though without quotation marks in my test). This worked too:

```
egrep -v "^(\r?\n)?$" filename.txt
```

Comment: Tried that. Blank lines are still showing. Could this be because the file was made in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

This code removes blank lines and lines that start with "#"

```
 grep -v "^#" file.txt | grep -v ^[[:space:]]*$
```

Comment: why not just a simple: `grep -vE '^$|#' file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NF' file-with-blank-lines > file-with-no-blank-lines
```

Answer (score 2):

It's true that the use of *grep -v -e '^$'* can work, however it **does not remove blank lines that have 1 or more spaces in them**.  I found the easiest and simplest answer for removing blank lines is the use of *awk*. The following is a modified a bit from the awk guys above:

```
awk 'NF' foo.txt
```

But since this question is for using grep I'm going to answer the following:

```
grep -v '^ *$' foo.txt
```

**Note**: the blank space between the ^ and *.

Or you can use the \s to represent blank space like this:

```
grep -v '^\s*$' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried hard, but this seems to work (assuming `\r` is biting you here):

```
printf "\r" | egrep -xv "[[:space:]]*"
```

Comment: That works if I replace the first part with output from the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

(1) **show** only non-empty lines:

```
grep .
```

or

```
grep '\S'
```

or

```
grep '[[:graph:]]'
```

(2) **hide** empty lines:

```
grep -v '^$'
```

or better:

```
grep -v '^\s*$'
```

or

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'
```

- `.` or `'.'` = pattern matching any character `.` except line break (typically patterns should be quoted when grep is used in a shell command, but in this case we can skip them)
- `'\S'` = pattern, where `\S` stands for a character that is **not** a white space character (read more on [pcre2syntax](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcre2syntax.3.html) - Perl-compatible regular expressions)
- `'[[:graph:]]'` = pattern, where `[[:xxxxx:]]` stands for positive POSIX named set, and `graph` for pcre2syntax's [character class](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC8) "printing, excluding space"
- `-v` = invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines (read more on [grep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)'s *Matching Control* options)
- `'^$'` = pattern, where `^` stands for [start of line](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#carmulti), and `$` for [end of line](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#eol) (which equals to empty lines) - this will work with **LF** [end of line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) sequence (Unix and Unix-like systems)
- `\s*` = `\s` is a whitespace character and `*` means zero or more occurrences, so pattern `'^\s*$'` will work with both **LF** (Unix) and **CRLF** (Windows) end of line sequence
- `'^[[:space:]]*$'` = pattern, where `^` stands for start of line,  `[[:xxxxx:]]` for POSIX named set, `space` for PCRE2 character class "white space", `*` for zero or more occurrences and `$` for end of line - this will also work with LF and CRLF files

On some versions of grep you may also have to use this option:

- `-E` = *extended-regexp* - interpret pattern as extended regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
grep pattern filename.txt | uniq
```

Comment: `uniq` will reduce adjoining blank lines to just one blank line, but does not remove them completely.  Still, I like trying to use `uniq` like that.  Sorting first would effectively remove all blank lines--leaving just one, but rearranging the line order may not be acceptable.

Comment: Good point. This will also chomp repeated lines. I guess my solution introduces bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\S/'
```

`\S` means match non-blank characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of removing the white lines and lines starting with the `#` sign. I think this is quite useful to read configuration files.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sudoers | egrep -v '^(#|$)'
Defaults    requiretty
Defaults   !visiblepw
Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR
LS_COLORS"
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

egrep -v  "^\s\s+"

egrep already do regex, and the \s is white space.

The + duplicates current pattern.

The ^ is for the start

Answer (score 0):

Read lines from file exclude **EMPTY** Lines

```
grep -v '^$' folderlist.txt
```

folderlist.txt

```
folder1/test

folder2
folder3

folder4/backup
folder5/backup
```

Results will be:

```
folder1/test
folder2
folder3
folder4/backup
folder5/backup
```