# How to remove blank lines from above and below from a output

Tags: linux, redhat, aix

In Aix when I am running a command to get a status it is showing but there is few lines blank above and few below apart from the actual output line. How to remove while generating the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blank lines with grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432555/remove-blank-lines-with-grep)

Answer (score 0):

```
tr -d '\r' < "$file" > t ; mv t "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used sed to remove lines . I am not dealing with files. I am storing output to a variables. It worked . Thanks for the valuable time