# What are the differences between GNU grep's basic/extended and PCRE (`-P`) regular expressions?

Tags: regex, grep, gnu, pcre

GNU grep's basic (BRE) and extended (ERE) syntax is documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html and PCRE is summarized at `man pcresyntax`, but there is no explicit comparison. What are the differences between GNU grep's basic/extended and PCRE (`-P`) regular expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My research of the major syntax and functionality differences from http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html:

- `.` in GNU grep does not match [null bytes](https://superuser.com/questions/507267/how-to-grep-for-special-character-nul) and [newlines](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Introduction) (but does match newlines when used with `--null-data`), while Perl, everything except `\n` is matched.
- `[...]` in GNU grep defines POSIX bracket expressions, while Perl uses "character" classes. I'm not sure on the details. See http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html#bracketexpression
- "In basic regular expressions the meta-characters `?`, `+`, `{`, `|`, `(`, and `)` lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions `\?`, `\+`, `\{`, `\|`, `\(`, and `\)`." From https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html. ERE matches PCRE syntax.
- GNU grep `\w` and `\W` are the same as `[[:alnum:]]` and `[^[:alnum]]`, while Perl uses alphanumeric and underscore.
- GNU grep has `\<` and `\>` for start and end of word.

Perl supports much more additional functionality:

- "nongreedy {}" with syntax `re{...}?`
- additional anchors and character types `\A`, `\C`, `\d`, `\D`, `\G`, `\p`, `\P`, `\s`, `\S`, `\X`. `\Z`, `\z`.
- `(?#comment)`
- shy grouping `(?:re)`, shy grouping + modifiers `(?modifiers:re)`
- lookahead and negative lookahead `(?=re)` and `(?!re)`, lookbehind and negative lookbehind `(?<=p)` and `(?<!p)`
- Atomic groups `(?>re)`
- Conditional expression `(?(cond)re)`
- ... and more, see `man pcresyntax`

Comment: One important point that I found very helpful once I realized it: in GNU grep, BRE and ERE are functionally *identical* – they only differ in what needs to be escaped. This isn't true for BRE and ERE in general; for example, POSIX BRE doesn't support "one or more" via `\+`, only via `\{1,\}`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. true, I didn't even consider POSIX BRE in my question or answer.